# Java Android code in WinDev

Tags: windev

I'm new in WinDev and I'm trying to create an Android application on a honeywell device with a barcode scanner.
I tried 2 different ways in Android Studio and they work.
One is the following:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.honeywell.scanintent.ScanIntent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView barcodeData = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        barcodeData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void onSendButtonClick(View v) {
        Intent intentScan = new Intent(ScanIntent.SCAN_ACTION);
        intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        int loadmode = 0;

        intentScan.putExtra("scan_mode",ScanIntent.SCAN_MODE_RESULT_AS_URI);
        this.startActivityForResult(intentScan, 5);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode == ScanIntent.SCAN_RESULT_SUCCESSED) {
            String data = intent.getStringExtra(ScanIntent.EXTRA_RESULT_BARCODE_DATA);
            int format = intent.getIntExtra(ScanIntent.EXTRA_RESULT_BARCODE_FORMAT, 0);
            barcodeData.setText(data);
        }
        else{
            barcodeData.setText("FALLITO");
        }
    }
}
```

And the other way is this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.honeywell.decodemanager.DecodeManager;
import com.honeywell.decodemanager.SymbologyConfigs;
import com.honeywell.decodemanager.barcode.DecodeResult;
import com.honeywell.decodemanager.symbologyconfig.SymbologyConfigCode39;


public final class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final int ID_SCANSETTING = 0x12;
    private final int ID_CLEAR_SCREEN = 0x13;
    private final int SCANKEY        = 0x94;
    private DecodeManager mDecodeManager = null;
    private TextView mDecodeResultEdit = null;
    private final int SCANTIMEOUT = 2000;
    long mScanAccount = 0;
    private boolean mbKeyDown = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mDecodeResultEdit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        try {
                            if (mbKeyDown) {
                                DoScan();
                                mbKeyDown = false;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        try {
                            mbKeyDown = true;
                            cancleScan();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
        private void DoScan() throws Exception {
            try {
                mDecodeManager.doDecode(SCANTIMEOUT);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mDecodeManager == null) {
            mDecodeManager = new DecodeManager(this ,ScanResultHandler);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mDecodeManager != null) {
            try {
                mDecodeManager.release();
                mDecodeManager = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private Handler ScanResultHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case DecodeManager.MESSAGE_DECODER_COMPLETE:
                    String strDecodeResult = "";
                    DecodeResult decodeResult = (DecodeResult) msg.obj;
                    strDecodeResult = "Decode Result::"+ decodeResult.barcodeData;

                    mDecodeResultEdit.setText(strDecodeResult);
                    break;

                case DecodeManager.MESSAGE_DECODER_FAIL:
                    mDecodeResultEdit.setText("FAILED");
                    break;

                case DecodeManager.MESSAGE_DECODER_READY:
                {
                    try {
                        SymbologyConfigCode39 code39 = new SymbologyConfigCode39();
                        code39.enableCheckEnable(false);
                        code39.enableSymbology(false);
                        code39.setMaxLength(48);
                        code39.setMinLength(2);

                        SymbologyConfigs symconfig = new SymbologyConfigs();

                        symconfig.addSymbologyConfig(code39);
                        mDecodeManager.setSymbologyConfigs(symconfig);

                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                    break;

                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private void cancleScan() throws Exception {
        mDecodeManager.cancelDecode();
    }
}
```

On WinDev I created a GLOBAL JAVA PROCEDURE and I generated the application, importing the honeywell library, but I don't understand how to implement the android native functions. How can I do this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First add a Global Procedure set to your project and then in this set create an empty Global procedure.

Once the procedure is created on its header bar click on the letters **WL** and it will convert to JAVA code mode. Now paste you JAVA code!

HTH

Yogi Yang